# overide global Validation Bindings validationOptions for specific input

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have the standard validation options applied on script initialisation:

```
ko.validation.configure({
        insertMessages: false,
        decorateInputElement: true,
        errorClass: 'has-error',
        errorElementClass: 'has-error'
    });
```

This is working perfectly, however I have a user acceptance checkbox that makes sense to have the `alert alert-danger` classes applied when the view model is invalid.

I have tried applying the following and overriding the global validation options with ones that apply locally to the container (as per [Validation Bindings wiki](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings)):

```
<div data-bind="validationOptions: { decorateInputElement: true, errorClass: 'koErrorElement', errorelementclass: 'koErrorElement' }">
    <div class="checkbox" data-bind="validationElement: hasAgreedToTerms">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: hasAgreedToTerms" /> I agree to terms and conditions
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work, it only applies the original `has-error` class (that is set during init) and applies it to the checkbox element (whereas i want it wrapped on the containing div.checkbox element. The output I would expect to be produced would be the following html:

```
<div class="checkbox koErrorElement">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> I agree to terms and conditions
    </label>
</div>
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong and why the error classes are not applied?

Comment: `errorelementclass` should be `errorElementClass` the casing **does** matter...

Comment: A set of fresh eyes does wonders, fancy popping an answer on so i can close the question? I am now using `<div data-bind="validationOptions: { decorateInputElement: true, errorElementClass: 'koErrorElement' }">` and works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the the [configuration's documentation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration) the correct property name is `errorElementClass` and not `errorelementclass` as you have it in your code.

So you just need to use the correct casing of the option `errorElementClass`:

```
<div data-bind="validationOptions: { decorateInputElement: true, 
                                     errorElementClass: 'koErrorElement' }">
    <div class="checkbox" data-bind="validationElement: hasAgreedToTerms">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: hasAgreedToTerms" /> 
            I agree to terms and conditions
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```